# Mini Cooper base

Tags: electrical, transmission, clutch, mini-cooper

The shift cable bushing broke. I replaced it. I had to replace the slave cylinder and master cylinder.   I have bled the clutch.  I have a good clutch pedal with the car running and I can put it in first gear. It will not move with the car running.

I can put it in first and I don't have to push the clutch in.  I’ve checked the splines on the axel and on the driver side with the car jacked up.  I can spin the wheel with the car in first gear, it will start to spin the passenger side but it will not spin it.

I've worked on cars and semis all my life, this car has been down for a month I hope someone can help me please.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! You state you can put it in first gear ... can you also put it into the other gears?

Comment: you should seek out a mini-specific forum. They are notoriously difficult to properly bleed the clutch and there are detailed write ups on the subject if you do a little searching.